# Reshaping the array returned by matplotlib.pyplot.imread(*args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, reshape

`matplotlib.pyplot.imread(*args, **kwargs)` returns a MxNx3 for RGB images (where M and N are the height and width of the image and 3 is the number of R, G, and B channels). How should I reshape the output to 3xMxN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `arr` as the input array, you can use [`np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) -

```
arr.transpose(2,0,1)
```

Or [`np.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) -

```
np.rollaxis(arr,2,start=0)
```

Comment: That was really fast answer! Thanks a lot! :)